# No input file specified error but file exists

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm trying to start using Laravel/Homestead

I got vagrant running with my homestead box and everything works right. I got a folder on my desktop called box.
This is my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/Desktop/box
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: bolivar.local
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/Bolivar/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

However when I type bolivar.local I get No input file specified. What am I missing?

Comment: There could be so many reasons. Did you run init.sh/init.bat? Did you run vagrant up? Does 192.168.10.10 shows you Laravel home page?

Comment: Vagrant is up. 

init.sh/init.bat - no. Where do i run this? I did run bash init.sh and it did created the Homestead.yaml as stated in the Laravel tutorial "The Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead directory."

No Laravel homepage is shown

Comment: Please read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead - maybe you missed few steps. Does 192.168.10.10 address works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the site to your HOSTS file to be redirected.

`192.168.10.10  bolivar.local`